# Cursor trail in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html5-canvas

i had followed a youtube vedio to do a cursor trail using vanilla js , now i am trying to write that code in react

so i was trying to write the code in Canvas.tsx file
i with the help of chatgpt came with this code

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./canvas.css";

const Canvas = () => {
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
  const [ctx, setCtx] = useState<CanvasRenderingContext2D | null>(null);
  const [particlesArray, setParticlesArray] = useState<Particle[]>([]);
  const [hue, setHue] = useState(0);
  const [mouse, setMouse] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  // useEffect to initialize canvas and context
  useEffect(() => {
    // Get canvas element by ID
    const canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas1") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    const context = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

    // Set canvas and context in state
    setCanvas(canvasElement);
    setCtx(context);

    // Set canvas dimensions and add a resize listener
    canvasElement.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvasElement.height = window.innerHeight;

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      canvasElement.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvasElement.height = window.innerHeight;
    });

    // Add mousemove event listener to update mouse position
    canvasElement.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
      setMouse({ x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY });
    });
  }, []);

  class Particle {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    size: number;
    speedX: number;
    speedY: number;

    constructor() {
      this.x = mouse.x;
      this.y = mouse.y;
      this.size = Math.random() * 15 + 1;
      this.speedX = Math.random() * 6 - 3; // Adjust the speed values as needed
      this.speedY = Math.random() * 6 - 3;
    }

    update() {
      this.x += this.speedX;
      this.y += this.speedY;
      if (this.size > 0.2) this.size -= 0.1;
    }

    draw() {
      if (ctx) {
        ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
      }
    }
  }

  function handleParticles() {
    const newParticlesArray = particlesArray.filter((particle) => particle.size > 0.2);
    setParticlesArray(newParticlesArray);
  }

  function animate() {
    if (ctx && canvas) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      handleParticles();
      setParticlesArray((prev) => [...prev, new Particle()]);
      setHue((prevHue) => (prevHue + 1) % 360); // Cycle through hues
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ctx && canvas) {
      animate();
    }
  }, [ctx, canvas]);
  return (
    <div>
      <canvas id="canvas1" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Canvas;
```

,
The animation is not showing on browser
I am unable to understand why this code is unable to show anything on my screen need help with this , is there any other way by which i can implement cursor trail on react it will help a lot , i am new with react .